# sequence number generate for web application

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier, web

The requirement : it is require to generate a unique, number for a each and every web request, this number is used to identify the transaction uniquely and track the transaction propagation and this number will return to client for future reference. this is a java web application i would like to know the methods available to do this..(without connenct db get a key value)Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are running only single instance of your application, simply use [AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet%28%29). However it needs to be persisted prior to shutdown, otherwise it will always start from `0` after restart.

Otherwise [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class has to be used which is universally unique 128-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the java [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)?

Here is a tutorial on how to [generate them](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56)